# Dart dynamically get an instance of a class from another file

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get (by get I mean to create a new one) an instance of a class. This is what I did :

file_one.dart

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
  SendPort sendPort = spawnUri('file_two.dart');
  sendPort.call('get new instance')
    .then(print);
}
```

file_two.dart

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:mirrors';

class TestClass {}

void main() {
  port.receive((message, SendPort replyTo) {
    MirrorSystem current = currentMirrorSystem();
    LibraryMirror isolate = current.isolate.rootLibrary;
    Map classes = isolate.classes;
    ClassMirror test = classes[const Symbol('TestClass')];
    TestClass testClass = test.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
    replyTo.send(testClass);
  });
}
```

It prints nothing, but if I send a string e.g 'SomeString' it prints 'SomeString'. Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send `testClass` through port because according to [dart:isolate - Concurrency with Isolates](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-dartisolate---concurrency-with-isolates) :

> The content of a message can be any of the following:
>
> - A primitive value (null, num, bool, double, String)
> - An instance of SendPort
> - A list or map whose elements are any of the above, including other lists and maps
> - In [special circumstances](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-sending-any-type-of-object), an object of any type

There's also [an issue to allow Transferable Objects for Dart's Isolates](http://dartbug.com/4149) that could change this behaviour in the future.